# Getting only system emails, although deliverability has been set to 'all emails'

Tags: email

I have email deliverability set to 'All emails' in my recently refreshed sandbox. but i am getting only system generated emails, not the workflow triggered emails.
Also, not received single email when performed the 'Test Deliverability'

I do not think this is related to IP ranges since I am getting system generated mails.

What could be other the reason? Any idea?

Comment: How are you sending the emails? Are they going to a user? Sandboxes change user's email addresses.

Comment: I am using workflows with additional email Id to check, and using proper email id while doing test deliverability

Comment: note testmethods never send email, even through workflows